# Command mode in Jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

Does jupyterlab ditch the Jupyter notebook editing and execution norms?  I can not do the simplest action- that is to toggle into/out of the `command` mode using `esc`ape.  Instead the notebook remains in `edit` mode on the current cell.

Generally I am also at a loss on how to navigate among the various tabs and to/from the Editor pane *using keyboard only*.  An IDE must have strong support for keyboarding or it is the wrong one for me. Hopefully these shortcuts exist but I was unable to find them yet.

Comment: This doesn't sound right, I've been using Esc, command and arrows to navigate in JupyterLab for a long time. The only time things were more difficult was when using vim key-bindings - is it possible that you could have used non-standard key-bindings?

Comment: @krassowski . Actually your informal feedback is helpful:  to just hear that others are having success with this will make me try again. My laptop got wiped recently so I have "opportunity" of starting over -and will give `jupyterlab` another go.